# How to retrieve Locale in Spring Boot outside of the Dispatcherservlet context?

Tags: spring-boot, locale

All the sunny side up examples work perfectly when I try to receive the `Locale` been set by `CookieLocaleResolver` using `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()`. But outside of the classic request-response-context I always seem to retrieve the Locale provided by the browser.

What I want to achieve is to get the current Locale set by the user from inside a `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`:

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private final MessageSource messageSource;

    public CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        String errorMessage = messageSource.getMessage("login.error", null, locale);

        //...
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

As someone mentioned in another post, the route through the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` is not handled by Springs Dispatcherservlet context. Thus I assume, we're inside another `Thread` and as far as I know, the Locale gets stored in a `ThreadLocal` variable.

In case I am right, as well in case I'm wrong, how can I retrieve the users Locale outside the sunny side up happy path?

**Many thanks for any help and/or additional information**

### Edit

So, after some debugging I found out, that the whole authentication process takes place within the same thread. Apparently Spring Boot doesn't seem to read the locale from the cookie during the authentication process and thus doesn't put it into the LocaleContextHolder. Currently, the earliest access  I do have to the HttpServletRequest is within a custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, and at this point of the request-response cycle the locale isn't been set yet.

Do I really have to code my own solution for something that imo should be standard?

#### Current solution:

As for now I inject the `LocaleResolver` into the `AuthenticationFailureHandler` so I can resolve the locale implicitly without relying on Spring Boot's automatism. If there is a better solution, please let me know.